# I have a A = 3×3 matrix in which position of elements are to be shuffled based on polynomial function result

Tags: polynomials, matrix-indexing

```
A =  [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
```

Now reshaping the matrix A to form a row vector gives B.

```
B = [1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9];
```

Evaluating polynomial function

f(x) = (7x+6x^2+3x^3)mod 9 
by putting values for 'x' ranging from (1,...,9) since there are 9 elements.

Ex. For x=1, f(x) = 16 mod 9 = 7

For x=2, f(x) = 62 mod 9 = 8 till x = 9 results in permute.

```
permute = [7 8 3 1 2 6 4 5 9];
```

permute vector gives positions. 
Using matrix indexing, the positions of elements in row vector B are arranged according to permute vector resulting in enc.

```
enc = B(permute);
%enc = [3 6 7 1 4 8 2 5 9]
```

Thus, the original position of elements in A has been shuffled represented by new_A.

```
new_A = [3 1 2;6 4 5;7 8 9]; %reshaping new_A = (enc,3,3)
```

To get original matrix back, new_A is reshaped into a row vector 'dec' again.

```
dec = [3 6 7 1 4 8 2 5 9];
dec(permute) = dec;
dec = [1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9];
org_mat= reshape(dec,3,3)
org_mat = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8  9];
```

How does dec(permute)= dec works in this?

Comment: It's possible you haven't gotten a response yet because the question is a bit unclear. For example, in your first code block, you define B twice, if you are trying to give the value B would become, you should write it outside the code or in a comment. As it is, its not clear what is code and what is explanation.

Comment: Apologies for inconvenience. I will present this query properly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it works is because `dec = enc = B(permute)`.

If you simply replace this into `dec(permute) = dec;` you get `dec(permute) = B(permute)` (only replace the second `dec`.) This gives you `dec=B`.

This is a general result. For example, for any permutation vector `p` and vectors `X` and `Y` then if you set `X(p)=Y(p)` then `X=Y` because your placing the p'th element from `Y` into the p'th element in `X` thus exactly preserving `Y`.

Finally, since `dec=B` and you created `B` using `B=reshape(A,1,9)` then of course, `reshape(dec,3,3)` gives you back `A` as this is equivalent to `reshape(B,3,3)` which just undoes the original reshape.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I got that dec(permute) = dec applies inverse of permute.

Comment: Sir, you explained the general result. Is that the specific property defined in MATLAB?

Comment: Yes, matlab syntax defines the meaning of `X(p)=z` as "place `z` into the p'th position in `X`" and the meaning of `z=Y(p)` as "take the p'th element in `Y` and place it in `z`" The two together give "place the p'th element from `Y` into the p'th position in `X` which, if `p` is a permutation vector equivalent to simpily setting `X=Y`. If you need more understanding see 

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/indexed-assignment.html